# S3 signed upload using bash getting "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

this is the code I am using for testing the upload file to s3 using presigned url

```
###... CODE TO SET VALUES FOR BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_KEY, FILE_PATH ...###

# Generate a presigned URL
PRESIGNED_URL=$(aws s3 presign s3://$BUCKET_NAME/$OBJECT_KEY --expires-in 3600 --region $REGION)

# Check if the presigned URL was generated successfully
if [ -z "$PRESIGNED_URL" ]; then
    echo "Failed to generate a presigned URL"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Presigned URL: $PRESIGNED_URL"

# Upload the file using curl with the matching Content-Type header
curl -X PUT -T "$FILE_PATH" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/zip" \
  "$PRESIGNED_URL"
```

but this is returning this error

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA*****</AWSAccessKeyId>
```